# AWS EVENTBRIDGE: Add content filtering to ECS task state changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to create an eventbridge rule whenever ECS task is deleted abnormally.

Normally ECS sends all events event the created or attached states too but I want to filter only `DELETED`state.

I am using CDK to create my event rule. I am trying to implement content filtering based on status which is present in attachment field which is again a part of detail field.

Sample event from ECS Task ->

```json
    {
        "version": "0",
        "id": "3317b2af-7005-947d-b652-f55e762e571a",
        "detail-type": "ECS Task State Change",
        "source": "aws.ecs",
        "account": "111122223333",
        "time": "2020-01-23T17:57:58Z",
        "region": "us-west-2",
        "resources": [
            "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:111122223333:task/FargateCluster/c13b4cb40f1f4fe4a2971f76ae5a47ad"
        ],
        "detail": {
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "id": "1789bcae-ddfb-4d10-8ebe-8ac87ddba5b8",
                    "type": "eni",
                    "status": "ATTACHED",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "name": "subnetId",
                            "value": "subnet-abcd1234"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "networkInterfaceId",
                            "value": "eni-abcd1234"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "macAddress",
                            "value": "0a:98:eb:a7:29:ba"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "privateIPv4Address",
                            "value": "10.0.0.139"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "availabilityZone": "us-west-2c",
            "clusterArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:111122223333:cluster/FargateCluster",
            "containers": [
                {
                    "containerArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:111122223333:container/cf159fd6-3e3f-4a9e-84f9-66cbe726af01",
                    "lastStatus": "RUNNING",
                    "name": "FargateApp",
                    "image": "111122223333.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/hello-repository:latest",
                    "imageDigest": "sha256:74b2c688c700ec95a93e478cdb959737c148df3fbf5ea706abe0318726e885e6",
                    "runtimeId": "ad64cbc71c7fb31c55507ec24c9f77947132b03d48d9961115cf24f3b7307e1e",
                    "taskArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:111122223333:task/FargateCluster/c13b4cb40f1f4fe4a2971f76ae5a47ad",
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "attachmentId": "1789bcae-ddfb-4d10-8ebe-8ac87ddba5b8",
                            "privateIpv4Address": "10.0.0.139"
                        }
                    ],
                    "cpu": "0"
                }
            ],
            "createdAt": "2020-01-23T17:57:34.402Z",
            "launchType": "FARGATE",
            "cpu": "256",
            "memory": "512",
            "desiredStatus": "RUNNING",
            "group": "family:sample-fargate",
            "lastStatus": "RUNNING",
            "overrides": {
                "containerOverrides": [
                    {
                        "name": "FargateApp"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "connectivity": "CONNECTED",
            "connectivityAt": "2020-01-23T17:57:38.453Z",
            "pullStartedAt": "2020-01-23T17:57:52.103Z",
            "startedAt": "2020-01-23T17:57:58.103Z",
            "pullStoppedAt": "2020-01-23T17:57:55.103Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-01-23T17:57:58.103Z",
            "taskArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:111122223333:task/FargateCluster/c13b4cb40f1f4fe4a2971f76ae5a47ad",
            "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:111122223333:task-definition/sample-fargate:1",
            "version": 4,
            "platformVersion": "1.3.0"
        }
    }
```

cdk code

```js
    {
            eventPattern: {
              source: ['aws.ecs'],
              detailType: ['ECS Task State Change'],
              detail: {
                clusterArn: [cluster.clusterArn],
                attachments: [{ status: [{ prefix: 'DELETED' }] }] // this is not working
              },
            },
          }
```

Comment: Does the `detail.attachments` list always have only one element?

Comment: Yes, it havs only one object, you can check the sample event i have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Edit: It *is* possible to filter on objects within arrays

```js
detail: { "attachments": {"status": ["DELETED"] } }
```

---

<s>EventBridge can match scalars in an array, but not arbitrary objects in an array:</s>

> [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-arrays.html): If the value in the event is an array, then the event pattern matches if the intersection of the event pattern array and the event array is non-empty.

That means EventBridge cannot match only `"status": "DELETED"`.  What are your options?

1. Base your pattern on a correlated non-array key-value pair, e.g. `"lastStatus": "STOPPED"`.
2. Match all patterns. Add logic to the event target to ignore uninteresting patterns.

Note: because you say the array reliably has only one element, you can [transform the event detail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-transform-target-input.html#eb-transform-input-cfn) before it gets sent to the target.  This does not help with the matching problem, but can make downstream filtering easier.  Here is a CDK example for a Lambda target:

```js
rule.addTarget(
  new targets.LambdaFunction(func, {
    event: events.RuleTargetInput.fromObject({
      status: events.EventField.fromPath('$.detail.attachments[0].status'),
      original: events.EventField.fromPath('$'),
    }),
  })
);
```

The Lambda receives the reshaped event detail:

```json
{
  "status": "ATTACHED",
  "original": <the original event>
}
```

Comment: Thanks @fedonev, "lastStatus":"DEPROVISIONING" worked for me.